# I am trying to install xlsx package in Rstudio but I am getting errors

Tags: r, r-xlsx

Trying to install xlsx package in Rstudio on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS type - 64bit but getting errors while installation. Please guide me as how to solve these errors as I am trying to create a script where I can read an Excel file commute some statistics on the column data

```
install.packages("xlsx")
Installing package into ‘/home/supratech/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-
library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘rJava’, ‘xlsxjars’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 656615 bytes (641 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 641 KB

trying URL   
'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xlsxjars_0.6.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 9477071 bytes (9.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 9.0 MB


trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xlsx_0.5.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 312839 bytes (305 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 305 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
** package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
configure: checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 supports static inline...
yes
checking whether setjmp.h is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking whether sigsetjmp is declared... yes
checking whether siglongjmp is declared... yes
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : ''
java libs   : ''
configure: error: One or more Java configuration variables are not  
set.
Make sure R is configured with full Java support (including JDK). Run
R CMD javareconf
as root to add Java support to R.

If you don't have root privileges, run
R CMD javareconf -e
to set all Java-related variables and then install rJava.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/home/supratech/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for package ‘xlsxjars’
* removing ‘/home/supratech/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-   
library/3.3/xlsxjars’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘xlsxjars’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘rJava’, ‘xlsxjars’ are not available for package    
‘xlsx’
* removing ‘/home/supratech/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/xlsx’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘xlsx’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
  ‘/tmp/RtmpH45TY8/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: looks like the exact same output [as this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13462890/5977215)

Comment: ... of (if you want to avoid using Java) and can live with possibly less features use another package like `readxl`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get rJava on Ubuntu is to install it from the repositories instead of trying to install it directly from CRAN

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked.

Comment: @Mansi, Keep habit of accepting the answer OR upvoting the answer to keep contributors motivated.

Comment: I am totally new to stack overflow.. Thanks :)

Comment: @Mansi, We are here to Help you further, Here is Quick Guide to [StackOverflow Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)