# Error when installing RJDBC / odbc packages on RStudio Server AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, odbc, rstudio-server, rjdbc

I am trying to install the `RJDBC` and `odbc` packages on my instance of RStudio server, which is running on AWS:

```
> Sys.info()
                             sysname                              release                              version 
                             "Linux"        "4.14.104-78.84.amzn1.x86_64" "#1 SMP Mon Mar 4 19:19:37 UTC 2019" 
                            nodename                              machine                                login 
                     "ip-10-0-0-170"                             "x86_64"                            "unknown" 
                                user                       effective_user 
                           "rstudio"                            "rstudio"
```

I get the same error with both installs. All other packages install without issues

I thought it may be to do with the drivers, so i downloaded them from this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#download-jdbc-driver. But I still get the same error

The error message is printed below:

> Installing package into ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified) also installing the dependency ‘rJava’
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-10.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 672577 bytes (656 KB)
>   ================================================== downloaded 656 KB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RJDBC_0.2-7.1.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 16841 bytes (16 KB)
>   ================================================== downloaded 16 KB
>
> - installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
>     ** package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked checking for gcc... gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 checking whether the C compiler
>     works... yes checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
>     checking for suffix of executables...  checking whether we are cross
>     compiling... no checking for suffix of object files... o checking
>     whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes checking whether gcc
>     -m64 -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes checking for gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed checking how to run the C
>     preprocessor... gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -E checking for grep that handles
>     long lines and -e... /bin/grep checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
>     checking for ANSI C header files... yes checking for sys/wait.h that
>     is POSIX.1 compatible... yes checking for sys/types.h... yes checking
>     for sys/stat.h... yes checking for stdlib.h... yes checking for
>     string.h... yes checking for memory.h... yes checking for strings.h...
>     yes checking for inttypes.h... yes checking for stdint.h... yes
>     checking for unistd.h... yes checking for string.h... (cached) yes
>     checking sys/time.h usability... yes checking sys/time.h presence...
>     yes checking for sys/time.h... yes checking for unistd.h... (cached)
>     yes checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes checking whether
>     time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes configure: checking
>     whether gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 supports static inline... yes checking
>     whether setjmp.h is POSIX.1 compatible... yes checking whether
>     sigsetjmp is declared... yes checking whether siglongjmp is
>     declared... yes checking Java support in R... present: interpreter :
>     '/usr/bin/java' archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar' compiler    :
>     '/usr/bin/javac' header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah' cpp flags   :
>     '-I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux' java
>     libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm' checking whether
>     Java run-time works... yes checking whether -Xrs is supported... yes
>     checking whether -Xrs will be used... yes checking whether JNI
>     programs can be compiled... yes checking JNI data types... ok checking
>     whether JRI should be compiled (autodetect)... yes checking whether
>     debugging output should be enabled... no checking whether memory
>     profiling is desired... no checking whether threads support is
>     requested... no checking whether callbacks support is requested... no
>     checking whether JNI cache support is requested... no checking whether
>     headless init is enabled... no checking whether JRI is requested...
>     yes configure: creating ./config.status config.status: creating
>     src/Makevars config.status: creating R/zzz.R config.status: creating
>     src/config.h
>     === configuring in jri (/tmp/RtmpYw2al0/R.INSTALL1d6d38609879/rJava/jri) configure: running
>     /bin/sh ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local' 
>     --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=. checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu checking host system type...
>     x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu checking for gcc... gcc -m64 -std=gnu99
>     checking whether the C compiler works... yes checking for C compiler
>     default output file name... a.out checking for suffix of
>     executables...  checking whether we are cross compiling... no checking
>     for suffix of object files... o checking whether we are using the GNU
>     C compiler... yes checking whether gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 accepts -g...
>     yes checking for gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none
>     needed checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -m64 -std=gnu99
>     -E checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E checking for ANSI C header files...
>     yes checking Java version... 1.7.0_201 checking whether /usr/bin/javah
>     actually works... yes checking for target flags...  -target 1.4
>     -source 1.4 checking whether Java interpreter works... checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes checking whether JNI
>     programs can be run... yes checking JNI data types... ok checking
>     whether Rinterface.h exports R_CStackXXX variables... yes checking
>     whether Rinterface.h exports R_SignalHandlers... yes configure:
>     creating ./config.status config.status: creating src/Makefile
>     config.status: creating Makefile config.status: creating run
>     config.status: creating src/config.h
>     ** libs gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c Rglue.c -o Rglue.o Rglue.c:860:13: warning: ‘new_jrectRef’ defined but not used
>     [-Wunused-function]  static SEXP new_jrectRef(JNIEnv *env, jobject a,
>     const char *sig, SEXP dim ) {
>              ^~~~~~~~~~~~ gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c arrayc.c -o arrayc.o gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I.
>     -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c callJNI.c -o callJNI.o gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I.
>     -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c callback.c -o callback.o gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I.
>     -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c fields.c -o fields.o gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I.
>     -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c init.c -o init.o init.c: In function ‘RinitJVM_real’: init.c:274:28: warning: unused
>     variable ‘add_xrs’ [-Wunused-variable]
>        int len = LENGTH(e), add_xrs = 1, joi = 0;
>                             ^~~~~~~ gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c jri_glue.c -o jri_glue.o gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I.
>     -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c loader.c -o loader.o gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I.
>     -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c otables.c -o otables.o gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I.
>     -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c rJava.c -o rJava.o gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I.
>     -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -c tools.c -o tools.o gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o
>     rJava.so Rglue.o arrayc.o callJNI.o callback.o fields.o init.o
>     jri_glue.o loader.o otables.o rJava.o tools.o
>     -L/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR (cd ../jri && make) make[1]: Entering directory
>     `/tmp/RtmpYw2al0/R.INSTALL1d6d38609879/rJava/jri' make -C src JRI.jar
>     make[2]: Entering directory`
>     /tmp/RtmpYw2al0/R.INSTALL1d6d38609879/rJava/jri/src' /usr/bin/javac
>     -target 1.4 -source 1.4 -d . ../package-info.java ../RFactor.java ../REXP.java ../Rengine.java ../RList.java ../Mutex.java
>     ../RConsoleOutputStream.java ../RMainLoopCallbacks.java
>     ../RVector.java ../RBool.java warning: [options] bootstrap class path
>     not set in conjunction with -source 1.4 1 warning if [ -n
>     "/usr/bin/javah" ]; then /usr/bin/javah -d . -classpath .
>     org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine; fi gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -c -o Rengine.o
>     Rengine.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -O2 -g
>     -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux -I/usr/include/R -I/usr/include/R gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -c -o jri.o jri.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -O2 -g -pipe
>     -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux -I/usr/include/R -I/usr/include/R gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -c -o Rcallbacks.o Rcallbacks.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK
>     -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux -I/usr/include/R -I/usr/include/R gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -c -o Rinit.o Rinit.c -g -Iinclude 
>     -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/include/R -I/usr/include/R gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -c -o globals.o globals.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -O2 -g
>     -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -c -o rjava.o rjava.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_request_lock’: rjava.c:22:3: warning: ignoring return value of
>     ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result] 
>     write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong));
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ rjava.c: In function
>     ‘RJava_clear_lock’: rjava.c:30:3: warning: ignoring return value of
>     ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result] 
>     write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong));
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ rjava.c: In function
>     ‘RJava_request_callback’: rjava.c:39:3: warning: ignoring return value
>     of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
>     [-Wunused-result]    write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong) * 3);
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ rjava.c: In function
>     ‘RJava_init_ctrl’: rjava.c:51:3: warning: ignoring return value of
>     ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result] 
>     write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong));
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ rjava.c:52:3: warning: ignoring
>     return value of ‘read’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
>     [-Wunused-result]    read(resin, buf, sizeof(ptrlong) * 2);
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -o libjri.so
>     Rengine.o jri.o Rcallbacks.o Rinit.o globals.o rjava.o  -shared
>     -L/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR -ltre -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm -licuuc -licui18n gcc: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory make[2]: *** [libjri.so] Error 1 make[2]:
>     Leaving directory
>     `/tmp/RtmpYw2al0/R.INSTALL1d6d38609879/rJava/jri/src' make[1]: ***
>     [src/JRI.jar] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory`
>     /tmp/RtmpYw2al0/R.INSTALL1d6d38609879/rJava/jri' make: *** [jri]
>     Error 2 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
> - removing ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘rJava’ had
>     non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for
>     package ‘RJDBC’
> - removing ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RJDBC’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘RJDBC’ had
>     non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘/tmp/RtmpSo7Mm5/downloaded_packages’

Comment: Please try to install `rJava` alone first

Comment: done, but got the same error unfortunately

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462890/cant-install-rjava-on-ubuntu-system

Comment: Thanks. Is there a Fedora equivalent to `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava`?

Comment: running this command allowed installation of the odbc pacakge: `yum install -y unixODBC*`

Comment: feel free to post you comment as an answer